# Como faço para mudar Header das colunas de uma gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

Como faço para conseguir dar um nome que eu queira ao header das colunas de uma gridview que seja criada dinamicamente no C# sem ser em ASP.NET por favor

Answer (score 3):

```
gridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Nome da Coluna";
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ColumnName.HeaderText = "Nome da Coluna";
```